# TeXForm: control processing spelt-out names of Greek letters

Tags: latex

In a notebook, type in

```
theta^2
```

then select it and use Copy As → LaTeX.  The resulting LaTeX code is

```tex
\text {theta}^2
```

Now try

```
TeXForm[theta^2]
(* \theta ^2 *)
```

Note that `theta` turned into `\theta` in the second case.

Why is there a difference between copying and using `TeXForm` directly?  How can I control whether spelt-out names of greek letters, such as `theta`, will be converted into the actual Greek letter, i.e. `\theta`?

---

One possible, but slightly inconvenient way to prevent the processing of such names is to replace them with strings, `theta -> "theta"`. I do not usually mind this processing (I actually prefer it), I am simply looking for a way to control it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has something to do with these:  `` Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[ToBoxes[theta^2]] `` and `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[theta^2] ``.  That and copying from a notebook deals with boxes and `TeXForm` deals with expressions.  `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX `` calls `` Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX `` with the option

```
"BoxRules" -> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords
```

but copying as TeX does not.

**Managing TeXForm**

`TeXForm[expr]` applies the list of rules `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords `` when it is typeset.

Demonstration:

```
Block[{System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords = {}},
 CellPrint@ExpressionCell[TeXForm[theta^2], "Output"]
 ]
```

[image]

Note that

```
Block[{System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords = {}},
 TeXForm[theta^2]
 ]
```

does not work because the output is `TeXForm[theta^2]`, which is then typeset after exiting the `Block[]`.  One can set the value of `$GreekWords` globally, so that `TeXForm[theta^2]` would be typeset without converting words to letters.

**Managing CopyAs > LaTeX**

This is but a partial answer.  Setting the following option should work to make *CopyAs > LaTeX* convert Greek letter names to letters, assuming `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords `` retains its default value:

```
SetOptions[Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX, 
  "BoxRules" -> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords];
```

On a Mac, it works when I use the context menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click, *CopyAs > LaTeX*).
However, I find it does not work with the menu-bar command *Edit > CopyAs > LaTeX*. (I have no clue why as yet, nor how it works on other systems.)

Comment: ``FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX`` does not override the default options to ``Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX``, fwiw.

Comment: This works though: `Block[{...}, ToString[theta^2, TeXForm]]` or `Block[{...}, ToString@TeXForm[...]]`.  Great spelunking, thanks!