# How can I make MMA give me \mathrm{d} when converting definite integrals into Latex code?

Tags: front-end, export, output-formatting, notebooks, latex

Recently my work contains a lot of expressions with definite integrals, and I need to convert them into latex code to present my results. To my disappointment, MMA always converts the differential operator `\[DifferentialD]` in those integrals into normal italic $d$, which does not conform to the regulations I need to obey.

In pure mathematics literature, using such normal italic $d$ notation for differential operator is common, but for physics and engineering literature, normal italic $d$ notation may already stand for a quantity or variable like distance or thickness, which has to be distinguished from the differential operator `\[DifferentialD]`,as a result I need to use "\mathrm{d}" or $\mathrm{d}$ to represent the differential operator in integrals.

I have already tried to modify the built-in Tex rules to achieve the "\mathrm{d}" in integrals. But unfortunately, it works when the expr is a pure differential. As long as it comes to a definite integral, it fails, which has given me a feelilng that the definite integral is parsed as whole in MMA and when doing so MMA ignores my self-introduced Tex rules.

My habitual way to generate latex code from MMA is right-click->Copy as->Latex. But I also welcome method that fulfill my needs by generating the latex code some other way in MMA.

Any ideas to achieve so?

Comment: Harder than I thought. Following instructions under [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132049/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47417/1871) post, I tried modifying ``System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex`` and ``System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$Operators``, but none of them seems to work. Looking forward to an answer.

Comment: could you post a MWE?

Comment: I agree with @Nasser . It's better to add corresponding code sample regarding to e.g. "I have already tried to modify the built-in Tex rules to achieve the "\mathrm{d}" in integrals…" That'll make the question more attractive.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser, but I am not sure what you meant by "MWE", so I do not quite know what you really wanted here

Comment: You may want to read this: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1162/1871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple enough as mentioned in the question:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["\[DifferentialD]"]="\\mathrm{d}";
```

should do the trick. And it actually does

```
"\[DifferentialD]"//TeXForm (* -> \mathrm{d} *)
```

> [image: plain dd]

But curiously

```
Integrate[f[x],x]//StandardForm
%//TeXForm (* -> \int f(x) \, dx *)
```

does not yield the expected result even though the `StandartForm` (boxed Mathematica representation) clearly uses `\[DifferentialD]`. The reason why the `TeXForm` is incorrect here is as OP guessed a problem and to be frank just a lazy oversight of the programmers of Mathematica:

```
GeneralUtilities`Definitions@System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex;
Select[ToString[#]&/@%,StringContainsQ[#,"integrand"]&];
%//TableForm
```

lets us look under the hood (the default tool of choice `PrintDefinitions` from `GeneralUtilities` does not work because it only prints when there are less then 257 definitions). From the 1059 definitions (in version 13) of `maketex` we select the ones which involve the string `"integrand"` and we get

```
HoldPattern[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{\[Integral], RowBox[{System`Convert`TeXFormDump`integrand_, RowBox[{\[DifferentialD], System`Convert`TeXFormDump`var_}]}]}]]] :> \int <>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`integrand]<> \, d<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`var]
HoldPattern[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox[\[Integral], System`Convert`TeXFormDump`sub_, System`Convert`TeXFormDump`super_, ___], RowBox[{System`Convert`TeXFormDump`integrand_, RowBox[{\[DifferentialD], System`Convert`TeXFormDump`var_}]}]}]]] :> \int_<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeScript[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`sub]<>^<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeScript[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`super]<> <>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`integrand]<> \, d<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`var]
```

with the critical segment `...\, d<>System...`. They clearly did not account for the option to properly set a `TeXForm` for `\[DifferentialD]`. Related to this is this discussion [What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821) on wether differential operators (and in this context mathematical constants like the imaginary unit, Eulers constant and even Pi) should be typeset upright. On a personal note: I like them upright (all of them including `\uppi` [see this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54166)) to clearly differentiate between operators/constant and variables. Coming back from my ramblings to the problem. Lets fix the two functions

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{"\[Integral]",RowBox[{integrand_,RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]",var_}]}]}]]:="\\int "<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[integrand]<> "\\," System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX["\[DifferentialD]"]<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[var]

System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox["\[Integral]", sub_,super_,___], RowBox[{integrand_, RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", var_}]}]}]] :="\\int_"<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeScript[sub]<>"^"<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeScript[super]<>" "<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[integrand]<> "\\,"<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX["\[DifferentialD]"]<>System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[var]
```

which fixes the issue for `Integrate`

```
Integrate[f[x],x]//StandardForm
%//TeXForm (* -> \int f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x *)
```

and

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // StandardForm
% // TeXForm  (* -> \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x*)
```

both work as expected:

> [image: Fixed]

as do multidimensional integrals. For occurrences of `\[DifferentialD]` outside of `Integrate` further modifications along this line will most likely be necessary. I personally would also consider to add a thin space `\,` or `\mkern2mu` between the differential operator and the variable.

The last side note related to earlier ramblings:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["\[DifferentialD]"]="\\mathrm{d}";
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["I"]="\\mathrm{i}";
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["E"]="\\mathrm{e}";
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["\[Pi]"]="\\uppi";
```

leads to the proper typesetting of Euler's formula (the solution for Pi is not ideal but it normally only appears in Mathematica as the mathematical constant)

```
Exp[I Pi x] // StandardForm
% // TeXForm (* -> \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\uppi x}*)
```

Comment: Interesting. It's worth mentioning that before re-defining `maketex[…]` it's necessary to execute e.g. `TeXForm[1]` once. BTW, do you have any idea about how to fix right-click->Copy as->LaTeX ?

Comment: Please file a bug report for this (if you have not already done so).

Comment: @xzczd I did not realize that but important to know. Regarding your question about Copy as -> LaTeX: I do not know how to do this. There are some questions and answers in this direction on this page but I was unable to get it to work. Interestingly one can completely clear all definitions from maketex and Copy as -> LaTeX still works, while TeXForm no longer does. I have no idea how to get them to work consistently.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Technically this is not a bug (I suppose) but rather a missing feature. They never intended to use a custom form for `\[DifferentialD]`. The whole LaTeX formatting code/functionality seems a bit hacked together to be honest and they should probably overhaul it. But I have the feeling this is not a priority since at least Stephen Wolfram pushes for the idea to have everything in Mathematica/Notebooks. This is in my opinion also the reason for other poorly implemented export functions. Like exporting plots as pdfs.

Comment: [Daniel](https://community.wolfram.com/web/danl) is a member of WRI, so… :)

Comment: To be sure, there are numerous problems with TeXForm and with exporting (also TeXForm may well be both dated and not well designed, I'm not familiar with the history). Some issues I myself have raised in house. While these have not attained a level of high priority, they are no longer as far down as might have once been the case. And the CEO is nowadays well aware that they have an impact.

Comment: Thanks @N0va. Your answer has shed enormous light on my problem. And the illumination from your answer has enabled me to fulfill my needs but with an unexpected phenomenon observed.

Comment: Since there are too many clicks to generate the code by right-clilck->Copy As->LaTex, I have modified the initial file with the code `MenuItem["Plain &Text", FrontEnd`CopySpecial["PlainText"]],
         MenuItem["&LaTeX", KernelExecute[ToExpression["FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]"]],
         MenuKey["C", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}],
         MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]` . By that way my actual method to generate Latex code is Ctr+Shift+C, which is much more convenient. And from my previous experience, the ways to modify functional output `TeXForm[ ]` don't work at all with my Ctr+Shift+C way.

Comment: From my code you can see, the Ctr+Shift+C way works because it sets up a connection between the input alias and the `MenuItem["&LaTeX", KernelExecute[ToExpression["FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]"]]`. As a result, I had observed the way which works to modify the Ctr+Shift+C output also works for right-click->Copy As->Latex and vise versa. To make my post succinct, I always mentioned my way to do so as right-click->Copy As->Latex, omitting verbose details related to initial files modification. And thanks to your inspiration, I have just  managed to make my Ctrl+Shift+C way works to generate the upright d.

Comment: You can reference the 2nd answer in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132069 about how to manage the CopyAs > LaTeX. But an unexpected phenomenon has occurred this time: the way to have Ctr+Shitf+C successfully generate upright d has no impact on right click->Copy As-> Latex , which has made me realized that the `MenuItem["&LaTeX", KernelExecute[ToExpression["FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]"]]` are not always tied together to right click->Copy As-> Latex, but probably linked to menu-bar command Edit > CopyAs > LaTeX on my Windows although Michael reported the reverse result on his Mac in that post.

Comment: @AlbertLew Which version are you in? How do you set `BoxRules`? On _v12.3.1_, _win10_, after setting ``SetOptions[Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX, 
 "BoxRules" -> (System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$Operators /. ("\[DifferentialD]" -> "d") -> ("\[DifferentialD]" -> "\\mathrm{d}"))]``, Edit > CopyAs > LaTeX doesn't work, either. (I haven't modified `MenuItem[…]`, but this shouldn't be a problem? )

Comment: @xzczd. Definitely. Actually our MMA version and OS are identical but  after my modification, both the Edit > CopyAs > LaTeX and Ctr+Shift+C work like a charm. I did not adopt the way you mentioned. Instead, I set an additional box rules `RowBox[{"\[Integral]", 
   RowBox[{integrand_, RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", var_}]}]}] :> 
 "\\int " <> Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[integrand] <> "\\mathrm{d}" <> 
  Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[var]` into built-in ones.

Comment: @xzczd Reasons your way does not work might be:1. You should not only set the rules for the mere "\[DifferentialD]" only, it won't work as I tried it before. In addition to the mere symbol d rule, you have to set rules for the complete box structure of the univariate integral like N0va does in his example. Otherwise MMA will ignore your d rule since the integrals are pasesed as a whole.

Comment: @xzczd The 2nd place where your method is problematic: One of the annoying features of `TeXForm` is that "\Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX "
 overrides the default "BoxRules" of  "\Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX " by setting it equal to  "\System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords" , so you have to hook into it rather than "`$Operators"  or anywhere else to get TeXForm recognizing your self-defined TeX rules.  Finally, to make the Edit->Copy->Latex work, an elegant line of code `SetOptions[Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX, 
  "BoxRules" -> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords];` will do the trick.

Comment: @AlbertLew You can wrap the code with two backticks e.g. \`\`aaa\`bbb\`\` to format it properly. So, you've added the mentioned rule to ``System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords``? Perhaps you can add an answer to elaborate about how to fix ``FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]``?

Comment: Thanks @xzczd. It annoyed me quite a bit with the formatting problem of the code with inherent backticks, I never thought that two back-ticks will do the trick.  In terms of managing the ``FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]``, actually it is not my original idea, it is @Michael E2 's. So I'd better reference Michael's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47430/81664) rather than add my own post after Nova's.